# Model wont rotate when mouseclicked

Tags: lua, roblox

```lua
local handle = script.Parent.Door.Handle
local door = script.Parent.Door.Model

handle.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    handle:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(handle:GetPrimaryPartCFrame() * CFrame.fromEulerAngles(0,math.rad(90), 0)
end)
```

This code is supposed to make a handle for a door rotate when "Mouseclick" Fires
I cannot figure out the error

Script analysis states errors as being

> (6,1) Expected ')' (to close '(' at line 5), got 'end'
>
> (5,103) Expected 'end' (to close 'function' at line 4), got <eof>

Answer (score 0):

The `handle:SetPrimaryPartCFrame` line has a lot going on and the error is telling you that you forgot to close a set of parentheses.

By breaking up some of the lines, you can keep track of the parentheses groups.

```lua
local targetCFrame = handle:GetPrimaryPartCFrame() * CFrame.fromEulerAngles(0, math.rad(90), 0)
handle:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(targetCFrame)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot parantheses. If we take a look at it line by line with indentation, you'll see what's going wrong.

```
local handle = script.Parent.Door.Handle
local door = script.Parent.Door.Model

handle.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    handle:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(
        handle:GetPrimaryPartCFrame(
            handle:GetPrimaryPartCFrame() * CFrame.fromEulerAngles(
                0, math.rad(90), 0
            )
        )
    -- There is a bracket missing here.
end)
```

So the correction is:

```
local handle = script.Parent.Door.Handle
local door = script.Parent.Door.Model

handle.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    handle:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(
        handle:GetPrimaryPartCFrame(
            handle:GetPrimaryPartCFrame() * CFrame.fromEulerAngles(
                0, math.rad(90), 0
            )
        )
    )
end)
```